# Switching between a Chrome extension's popup's pages without reloading

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that has a popup with multiple pages. Before I started implementing all the pages in one HTML file, and hid `<div>`s depending on which page the user was currently on. Since this turned out to be a major hassle I decided to instead create an HTML file / JavaScript file for each page and switch between them

```
function toX() {
  chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'x.html' });
  window.location.href = 'x.html';
}
```

Unfortunately this causes the popup to "flicker" / "reload" (it closes the current page, then opens the next one) when switching between pages.

How can I prevent this from happening an make switching between pages smooth (it was smooth when hiding `<div>`s containing the HTML of the pages the user isn't on, but as I said, that's a huge hassle)? I was thinking something along the line of Jinja's template inheritance, but I'm not sure if that is possible with a Chrome extension.

Comment: You can show the pages in an iframe. When switching you'll create a second hidden iframe, wait until it loads, then show it instead the active one. Although a modern solution is to use an SPA framework/library ranging from a very simple one to React-tier.

Comment: @wOxxOm Which option would you recommend? I don't really want to spend too much time on rewriting this and have no experience with using either iframes or a SPA framework / library, so I'm not sure which. Any examples and / or tutorials you can provide regarding either would be greatly appreciated as well!